# User management with Digits (Fabric iOS)

Tags: firebase, backend, twitter-fabric, stormpath, fabric-digits

This is kinda open ended question. Just wanted to get some comments / views / pointers on my situation. Before I start with my question I would like to disclose that I have never worked on backend before.

I am trying to build backend for an iOS app that creates user account based on phone number, take some basic information from user such as first name, last name and address. Based on that information I am planning give custom suggestion of weather / whats around etc.

Now for authentication I am using Digits from twitter (https://docs.fabric.io/ios/digits/index.html). But I am not sure how to do whole user management as such. Example collecting more information assigned to same user who was authenticated using phone number.

I thought of using Google's Firebase and Stormpath for user management but they seem to have there own authentication flow. Is there a way to combine either of these with Digits?

Any comments / pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Stormpath on our iOS SDK. Unfortunately, we don't have an integration with Digits or phone number based login at the moment, although it's on the roadmap. While it's technically possible to integrate them, for a casual project, I'd suggest using Facebook / Google Login.

Digits is really cool and useful, but Digits' integration on the server side unfortunately doesn't come with many examples, and may be difficult for you to understand if you haven't done it before. Facebook / Google login is a bit easier to implement (or even Facebook's AccountKit for phone number auth).

For using Stormpath to build a backend + mobile app, I've written a set of tutorials you can use to do Facebook or Google login.

- [Build a REST API for your Mobile Apps using Node.js](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-build-rest-api-mobile-apps-using-node-js)
- [Build an iOS App in Swift that uses a REST API](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-note-taking-app-swift-ios)